# Extract to a new dataset the equal tuples of a column of tuples in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples

I have a dataFrame that starting with a list of `userid` access on an `id`, has the tuples of `userid's` that are repeated for a given `id`. Also it has the number of times this tuple is repeated, like this:

```
    id  id2 duplicates
0   a   b   [((us1, us2), 5), ((us2, us1), 3), ((us2, us4), 2)]
9   c   b   [((us1, us2), 5), ((us2, us1), 3), ((us2, us4), 2)]
```

So on the first line, we have that the tuple (us1, us2) appears 5 times

The code to generate this is here:

```
d = {'id': ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"], 
     'id2': ["b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"], 
     'userid': ["us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4", "us4", "us5", "us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4"],
     "time": [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}

    df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d).sort_values('time')
    df_test.groupby(['id','id2']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
    df_test['tuples']=  df_test.apply(lambda x: list(zip(df_test.userid[:-1].sort_index(), df_test.userid[1:].sort_index())), 1)
    df_test = df_test.drop_duplicates(['id'],keep='first').drop(['userid', 'time'], 1)
    df_test['duplicates'] = df_test.apply(lambda x: [(k,v) for k,v in Counter(x.tuples).items() if v>1], 1)
    df_test.drop('tuples',1)
```

What I do need now and I am not managing how-to is to find the tuples (on the column duplicates) that are repeated in different rows having the same `id2` but different `id`, so the result here should be a new dataFrame:

```
id     id2  duplicates
[a, c]  b   [(us1, us2), (us2, us1), (us2, us4)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with `explode`

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d).sort_values('time')
df_test.groupby(['id', 'id2']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
df_test['tuples'] = df_test.apply(
     lambda x: list(zip(df_test.userid[:-1].sort_index(), df_test.userid[1:].sort_index())), 1)
s=df_test.explode('tuples').groupby(['tuples','id2']).id.apply(pd.Series.unique).apply(tuple).reset_index()
s.groupby(['id','id2']).tuples.agg(list)
id      id2
(a, c)  b      [(us1, us2), (us2, us1), (us2, us4), (us4, us4...
Name: tuples, dtype: object
```